# how to set Click event on Xslt output

Tags: xslt

This is my XSLT file:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/> 
     <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="//child_4331">
              <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="@value" />   
                  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript" />
                  </xsl:attribute>  
             </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I set the click event on **child_4331** value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the output that you are trying to produce. It is not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve. If you are producing HTML you will likely want to generate a `<div>` or a `<span>` with an `onClick` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say, but I'm assuming you want to copy the **child_4331** element and add the **onclick** attribute.

I would get rid of the template matching '`/`' and create one to match '`child_4331`'.  Use `xsl:copy` to create a copy of the element and add the attribute inside it.  If the **child_4331** element has attributes or child elements you will want to use `xsl:apply-templates` to pick them up.

Here is a sample snippet.  Your solution may vary depending on your desired output.  I can't give you more without knowing what your source XML looks like and what you expect to see in the result.

```
<xsl:template match="child_4331">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
      <xsl:call-template name="GetOnClickJavaScript" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
```